# variable and value name for gather in tidyr

Tags: r, tidyr

I try to use gather function of tidyr package to convert wide data into a long one with following demo.

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
messy <- data.frame(
name = c("Wilbur", "Petunia", "Gregory"),
a = c(67, 80, 64),
b = c(56, 90, 50)
 )

gather(messy,drug, heartrate, a:b)
```

Although I have used **drug** and **heartrate** to indicate condition and value, however, it still names as the default one **variable** and **value**. Why?

Comment: Not able to reproduce the problem.  CAn you run it on a clean R session with only dplyr and tidyr loaded?  I am using `tidyr_0.3.1` and `dplyr_0.4.3`

Comment: Cool. After shutdown of the Rstudio and rerun the code again, it works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It must be something related with masking of functions.  It should work when you rerun the code on a fresh R sessioin with only `tidyr` and `dplyr` loaded.